# Creating an SVG animated dashed line with a transparent background

Tags: animation, svg, svg-animate

I have been playing around with this for hours and trying to think up a solution.

In this... https://jsfiddle.net/WebFlair/nc0zyjdq/78/

```
<div class="bg">

<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="400.000000pt" height="400.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 400.000000 400.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#b0225e" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M23.742,10.709
    c-2.305,23.611-8.81,46.563-9.021,70.829c-0.252,28.966,22.237,43.666,47.06,55.482c23.642,11.255,42.368,15.766,68.461,16.631
    c19.993,0.663,40.08,2.97,59.853-1.723c23.301-5.531,45.542-17.598,66.978-27.933c19.248-9.281,38.831-21.86,41.946-45.201
    c5.539-41.51-54.993-47.073-81.885-42.17C159.05,47.212,89.37,104.633,77.387,164.629c-5.896,29.522-4.312,60.884,12.703,86.354
    c19.17,28.697,49.512,49.927,78.596,67.591"/>

<path class="dashed" fill="none" stroke="white"  stroke-width="7" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="16" d="M23.742,10.709
    c-2.305,23.611-8.81,46.563-9.021,70.829c-0.252,28.966,22.237,43.666,47.06,55.482c23.642,11.255,42.368,15.766,68.461,16.631
    c19.993,0.663,40.08,2.97,59.853-1.723c23.301-5.531,45.542-17.598,66.978-27.933c19.248-9.281,38.831-21.86,41.946-45.201
    c5.539-41.51-54.993-47.073-81.885-42.17C159.05,47.212,89.37,104.633,77.387,164.629c-5.896,29.522-4.312,60.884,12.703,86.354
    c19.17,28.697,49.512,49.927,78.596,67.591"/>
</svg>
</div>
<style>
.bg {background:#eee;}
.dashed{
  stroke-dasharray: 14;
}
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
</style>
```

You will see a grey background and an animated white and pink dashed line.

Now I know this wont work in my example, but what I am trying to do is make the white part transparent so that it can be used on any background, keep the animation and the pink dashed line.

Can anyone think of a way to make that happen?  I have gone over everything I can think of and always need the white part in order to keep the animation.

Answer (score 3):

> but what I am trying to do is make the white part transparent so that
> it can be used on any background, keep the animation and the pink
> dashed line.

The idea is as follows: use three layers

1. The first bottom layer will have a white path
2. The middle layer will have exactly the same pink path
3. There will be a masking path on the top layer, which will gradually
   reveal the pink path

This uses the property of the mask when "stroke: white" shows the section of the pink path that is under it

And since the length of the masking path changes from zero to the maximum value (`stroke-dashoffset` decreases from the maximum `917` to zero), the growth of the pink path becomes visible

```
@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 917;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
```

*Clarification the maximum path length is `917px`*

***1. The first bottom layer will have a white path***

```css
.bg {background:#eee;}
#dashed  {
  stroke-dasharray: 14;
  fill:none;
  stroke:white;
  stroke-width:7;
  stroke-linejoin:round; 
 
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">

<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="400.000000pt" height="400.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 400.000000 400.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

   <!-- Bottom layer dashed white line -->
<path id="dashed" d="M23.742,10.709
    c-2.305,23.611-8.81,46.563-9.021,70.829c-0.252,28.966,22.237,43.666,47.06,55.482c23.642,11.255,42.368,15.766,68.461,16.631
    c19.993,0.663,40.08,2.97,59.853-1.723c23.301-5.531,45.542-17.598,66.978-27.933c19.248-9.281,38.831-21.86,41.946-45.201
    c5.539-41.51-54.993-47.073-81.885-42.17C159.05,47.212,89.37,104.633,77.387,164.629c-5.896,29.522-4.312,60.884,12.703,86.354
    c19.17,28.697,49.512,49.927,78.596,67.591"/>  
    
    
</svg>
</div>
<script>
  console.log(dashed.getTotalLength());
</script>
```

***2. The middle layer will have exactly the same pink path***

```css
 <style>
.bg {background:#eee;}
#dashed  {
  stroke-dasharray: 14;
  fill:none;
  stroke:white;
  stroke-width:7;
  stroke-linejoin:round; 
 
} 

#pink {
stroke-dasharray: 14;
  fill:none;
  stroke:#b0225e;
  stroke-width:7;
  stroke-linejoin:round; 
  mask:url(#msk);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">

<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="400.000000pt" height="400.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 400.000000 400.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">


   <!-- Bottom layer dashed white line -->
<path id="dashed" d="M23.742,10.709
    c-2.305,23.611-8.81,46.563-9.021,70.829c-0.252,28.966,22.237,43.666,47.06,55.482c23.642,11.255,42.368,15.766,68.461,16.631
    c19.993,0.663,40.08,2.97,59.853-1.723c23.301-5.531,45.542-17.598,66.978-27.933c19.248-9.281,38.831-21.86,41.946-45.201
    c5.539-41.51-54.993-47.073-81.885-42.17C159.05,47.212,89.37,104.633,77.387,164.629c-5.896,29.522-4.312,60.884,12.703,86.354
    c19.17,28.697,49.512,49.927,78.596,67.591"/>  
      <!-- Middle layer dashed pink line -->
     <path id="pink" d="M23.742,10.709
    c-2.305,23.611-8.81,46.563-9.021,70.829c-0.252,28.966,22.237,43.666,47.06,55.482c23.642,11.255,42.368,15.766,68.461,16.631
    c19.993,0.663,40.08,2.97,59.853-1.723c23.301-5.531,45.542-17.598,66.978-27.933c19.248-9.281,38.831-21.86,41.946-45.201
    c5.539-41.51-54.993-47.073-81.885-42.17C159.05,47.212,89.37,104.633,77.387,164.629c-5.896,29.522-4.312,60.884,12.703,86.354
    c19.17,28.697,49.512,49.927,78.596,67.591"/>

</svg>
</div>
```

***3. There will be a masking path on the top layer, which will gradually reveal the pink path***

```css
.bg {background:#eee;}
#dashed  {
  stroke-dasharray: 14;
  fill:none;
  stroke:white;
  stroke-width:7;
  stroke-linejoin:round; 
 
} 

#pink {
stroke-dasharray: 14;
  fill:none;
  stroke:#b0225e;
  stroke-width:7;
  stroke-linejoin:round; 
  mask:url(#msk);
} 

#maskLine {
  fill:none;
  stroke:white;
  stroke-width:7;
  stroke-dasharray: 917;
  stroke-dashoffset: 917;
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 917;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">

<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="400.000000pt" height="400.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 400.000000 400.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<defs>
  <mask id="msk">  
       <!-- A mask layer that reveals a dashed pink line -->
    <path id="maskLine"  d="M23.742,10.709
    c-2.305,23.611-8.81,46.563-9.021,70.829c-0.252,28.966,22.237,43.666,47.06,55.482c23.642,11.255,42.368,15.766,68.461,16.631
    c19.993,0.663,40.08,2.97,59.853-1.723c23.301-5.531,45.542-17.598,66.978-27.933c19.248-9.281,38.831-21.86,41.946-45.201
    c5.539-41.51-54.993-47.073-81.885-42.17C159.05,47.212,89.37,104.633,77.387,164.629c-5.896,29.522-4.312,60.884,12.703,86.354
    c19.17,28.697,49.512,49.927,78.596,67.591"/>  
  </mask>
</defs>

   <!-- Bottom layer dashed white line -->
<path id="dashed" d="M23.742,10.709
    c-2.305,23.611-8.81,46.563-9.021,70.829c-0.252,28.966,22.237,43.666,47.06,55.482c23.642,11.255,42.368,15.766,68.461,16.631
    c19.993,0.663,40.08,2.97,59.853-1.723c23.301-5.531,45.542-17.598,66.978-27.933c19.248-9.281,38.831-21.86,41.946-45.201
    c5.539-41.51-54.993-47.073-81.885-42.17C159.05,47.212,89.37,104.633,77.387,164.629c-5.896,29.522-4.312,60.884,12.703,86.354
    c19.17,28.697,49.512,49.927,78.596,67.591"/>  
      <!-- Middle layer dashed pink line -->
     <path id="pink" d="M23.742,10.709
    c-2.305,23.611-8.81,46.563-9.021,70.829c-0.252,28.966,22.237,43.666,47.06,55.482c23.642,11.255,42.368,15.766,68.461,16.631
    c19.993,0.663,40.08,2.97,59.853-1.723c23.301-5.531,45.542-17.598,66.978-27.933c19.248-9.281,38.831-21.86,41.946-45.201
    c5.539-41.51-54.993-47.073-81.885-42.17C159.05,47.212,89.37,104.633,77.387,164.629c-5.896,29.522-4.312,60.884,12.703,86.354
    c19.17,28.697,49.512,49.927,78.596,67.591"/>
    
</svg>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Filling, clearing the path on repeated clicks on the button "Play"

```js
var dash = true;

function play() {
  var path = document.getElementById('maskLine');
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = (dash) ? '0' : '917.00';
  dash = !dash;
}
```

```css
.bg {background:#eee;}
#dashed  {
  stroke-dasharray: 14;
  fill:none;
  stroke:white;
  stroke-width:7;
  stroke-linejoin:round; 
 
} 

#pink {
stroke-dasharray: 14;
  fill:none;
  stroke:#b0225e;
  stroke-width:7;
  stroke-linejoin:round; 
  mask:url(#msk);
} 

#maskLine {
  fill:none;
  stroke:white;
  stroke-width:7;
  stroke-dasharray: 917;
  stroke-dashoffset: 917;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 5s linear;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="play();">Play</button>
<div class="bg">

<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="400.000000pt" height="400.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 400.000000 400.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<defs>
  <mask id="msk">  
       <!-- A mask layer that reveals a dashed pink line -->
    <path id="maskLine"  d="M23.742,10.709
    c-2.305,23.611-8.81,46.563-9.021,70.829c-0.252,28.966,22.237,43.666,47.06,55.482c23.642,11.255,42.368,15.766,68.461,16.631
    c19.993,0.663,40.08,2.97,59.853-1.723c23.301-5.531,45.542-17.598,66.978-27.933c19.248-9.281,38.831-21.86,41.946-45.201
    c5.539-41.51-54.993-47.073-81.885-42.17C159.05,47.212,89.37,104.633,77.387,164.629c-5.896,29.522-4.312,60.884,12.703,86.354
    c19.17,28.697,49.512,49.927,78.596,67.591">
     </path>
        
     </path>    
  </mask>
</defs>

   <!-- Bottom layer dashed white line -->
<path id="dashed" d="M23.742,10.709
    c-2.305,23.611-8.81,46.563-9.021,70.829c-0.252,28.966,22.237,43.666,47.06,55.482c23.642,11.255,42.368,15.766,68.461,16.631
    c19.993,0.663,40.08,2.97,59.853-1.723c23.301-5.531,45.542-17.598,66.978-27.933c19.248-9.281,38.831-21.86,41.946-45.201
    c5.539-41.51-54.993-47.073-81.885-42.17C159.05,47.212,89.37,104.633,77.387,164.629c-5.896,29.522-4.312,60.884,12.703,86.354
    c19.17,28.697,49.512,49.927,78.596,67.591"/>  
      <!-- Middle layer dashed pink line -->
     <path id="pink" d="M23.742,10.709
    c-2.305,23.611-8.81,46.563-9.021,70.829c-0.252,28.966,22.237,43.666,47.06,55.482c23.642,11.255,42.368,15.766,68.461,16.631
    c19.993,0.663,40.08,2.97,59.853-1.723c23.301-5.531,45.542-17.598,66.978-27.933c19.248-9.281,38.831-21.86,41.946-45.201
    c5.539-41.51-54.993-47.073-81.885-42.17C159.05,47.212,89.37,104.633,77.387,164.629c-5.896,29.522-4.312,60.884,12.703,86.354
    c19.17,28.697,49.512,49.927,78.596,67.591"/>

</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a [mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask):

```css
.bg {
  background: #eee;
}

.dashed {
  stroke-dasharray: 14;
}

.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400.000000pt" height="400.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 400.000000 400.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
  <defs>
    <path id="dashed" class="dashed" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="7" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="14" stroke-miterlimit="16" d="M23.742,10.709
    c-2.305,23.611-8.81,46.563-9.021,70.829c-0.252,28.966,22.237,43.666,47.06,55.482c23.642,11.255,42.368,15.766,68.461,16.631
    c19.993,0.663,40.08,2.97,59.853-1.723c23.301-5.531,45.542-17.598,66.978-27.933c19.248-9.281,38.831-21.86,41.946-45.201
    c5.539-41.51-54.993-47.073-81.885-42.17C159.05,47.212,89.37,104.633,77.387,164.629c-5.896,29.522-4.312,60.884,12.703,86.354
    c19.17,28.697,49.512,49.927,78.596,67.591"/>
    <mask id="mask">
      <use xlink:href="#dashed"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#b0225e" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" mask="url(#mask)" d="M23.742,10.709
    c-2.305,23.611-8.81,46.563-9.021,70.829c-0.252,28.966,22.237,43.666,47.06,55.482c23.642,11.255,42.368,15.766,68.461,16.631
    c19.993,0.663,40.08,2.97,59.853-1.723c23.301-5.531,45.542-17.598,66.978-27.933c19.248-9.281,38.831-21.86,41.946-45.201
    c5.539-41.51-54.993-47.073-81.885-42.17C159.05,47.212,89.37,104.633,77.387,164.629c-5.896,29.522-4.312,60.884,12.703,86.354
    c19.17,28.697,49.512,49.927,78.596,67.591"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

You can also eliminate the duplicate path declaration by reusing the `path` defined in `defs`, but this would require additional changes, so, in order to not obfuscate things, I decided to not put that in my answer.